# django-shop skipping shipping

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-shop

I'm using django-shop and I don't know how to skip shipping because I don't need it.
I tried several methods but don't find an issue.

have someone an idea ?

I tried to copy the flate_rate shipping to do my own but I'm facing a problem no reverse match.

Here is my file :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from shop.util.decorators import on_method, shop_login_required, order_required


class PostShipping(object):
"""
This is just an example of a possible flat-rate shipping module, that
charges a flat rate defined in settings.SHOP_SHIPPING_FLAT_RATE
"""
    url_namespace = 'post'
    backend_name = 'La Poste'
    backend_verbose_name = _('La Poste')

    def __init__(self, shop):
        self.shop = shop  # This is the shop reference, it allows this backend
        # to interact with it in a tidy way (look ma', no imports!)
        self.rate = 0

@on_method(shop_login_required)
@on_method(order_required)
def view_process_order(self, request):
    """
    A simple (not class-based) view to process an order.

    This will be called by the selection view (from the template) to do the
    actual processing of the order (the previous view displayed a summary).

    It calls shop.finished() to go to the next step in the checkout
    process.
    """
    self.shop.add_shipping_costs(self.shop.get_order(request),
                                 'la poste',
                                 Decimal(self.rate))
    return self.shop.finished(self.shop.get_order(request))
    # That's an HttpResponseRedirect

@on_method(shop_login_required)
@on_method(order_required)
def view_display_fees(self, request):
    """
    A simple, normal view that displays a template showing how much the
    shipping will be (it's an example, alright)
    """
    ctx = {}
    ctx.update({'shipping_costs': Decimal(self.rate)})
    return render_to_response('shop/shipping/flat_rate/display_fees.html',
        ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def get_urls(self):
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', self.view_display_fees, name='flat'),
        url(r'^process/$', self.view_process_order, name='flat_process'),
    )
    return urlpatterns
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a glance at the [github repo](https://github.com/divio/django-shop/tree/master/shop/shipping/backends) it seems there's no setting to disable shipping. You can however define your own shipping backend to customize things (make shipping pass silently).

In case you are just selling digital products I would recommend you to write your own code, [it's not that hard.](http://www.packtpub.com/article/setting-up-complete-django-ecommerce-store-30-minutes)

Comment: I did it but I'm facing an error. I took the flat_rate shipping in example but it generate an error : NoReverseMatch at /shop/checkout/ship/
Reverse for 'post' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. It's because of the self.shop problem

Comment: You are missing an urlpattern 'post'. See the get_urls function how to set one up.

Comment: I fixed it ! thank you a lot ! I only had to add post in url_patterns